# Why ++i++ gives "L-value required error" in C?

Tags: c

In below code:

```
main()
{
  int i = 5;
  printf("%d", ++i++);
}
```

This Program is giving the error `"L-Value required"`.

Can some one tell me **:** Why compilation error?

Comment: Is that the only thing in the code?

Comment: Wonder how the first C programs in the world happen to be so esoteric!

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD OP question is why its l-value error, that is a good question to understand.

Comment: A C99 or C11 compiler complains about no return type on the function `main()` — it should return `int`; it also complains about no declaration of the function `printf()` — which is doubly crucial since it is a 'varargs' function so invoking it without a prototype in scope leads to undefined behaviour; and finally it complains about the illegal expression `++i++`.  And only in C99 or C11 is it legal not to return a value from `main()`; prior to that, you needed `return 0;` before the end.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Which is why I asked the question. The code is incomplete. The function declaration is incomplete. And it has no return value.

Comment: Nothing undefined here, it's a syntax error.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker yes its not undefined but conceptually its undefined behavior to doing like this. thats what I wrote this

Comment: @PHIfounder No this question doesn't duplicates with linked code! yes that code compiles with every compiler --result of which is Undefined,  While this question is about Compilation error. There `++` applied on **variable** here `++` applied on **expression**. It doesn't duplicates

Comment: Why users marking it duplicate with the linked question whereas its not.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yeah, I got that minute difference by the discussion going on , on this topic but anyway :)

Comment: Voted to reopen, the duplicate is incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Why you marked it as duplicate? I am not agree.

Comment: @haccks: I'm not the person who currently has the distinction of closing it as a duplicate.  If I previously tagged it as closable/duplicate, it is because the other question is also about `++i++` and I find it hard to believe that there is much to be said about it here that wasn't said there -- but I have not looked again now to validate that assumption.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; I think `++i++` doesn't invoke UB unlike that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc) and it is completely a different issue.

Comment: @haccks: You're right that `++i++` doesn't invoke UB; it is an outright violation of the rules of C (it is defined to be invalid) and completely inadmissible as an expression.  It looks completely parallel to the duplicate question.  The 'close as duplicate' is reasonable in my view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because  postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators, so the expression `++i++` is equivalent to  `++(i++)`, that is equivalent to  `++( i + 1)`. The compiler gives l-value error because you are applying `++` on an expression `(i++)` that is *not* a modifiable lvalue, so not a valid expression in [c](/questions/tagged/c) according to increment operator definition.

According to Dennis M. Ritchie's book: ["The C Programming Language"](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf):

> #### 2.8 Increment and Decrement Operators
>
> (page 44)
>
> The increment and decrement operators can only be applied to variables; an expression like `(i + j)++` is illegal. The operand must be a `modifiable lvalue` of arithmetic or pointer type.

**Related:** An interesting bug one may like to know about in gcc 4.4.5 is that expression `j = ++(i | i);` compiles that should produce l-value error. Read: [`j = ++(i | i);` and `j = ++(i & i);` should an error: lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860189/j-i-i-and-j-i-i-should-an-error-lvalue)

Additionally, modifying same variable more then once in an expression without an intervening [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) causes which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). To understand read [Explain these undefined behaviors in `i = i++ + ++i;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc).

Comment: I don't see how you can claim "undefined behavior because `i` is modified twice without a sequence point" and in the same breath explain that `i` is modified once.

Comment: Actually, postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators, so the `i+++` would be done first, but since the result of `i++` is an r-value and not an l-value and prefix `++` can only be applied to an l-value, the error message is given.  That's a problem before you get to the undefined behaviour of modifying a single variable more than once in an expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators` ? no prefix evaluates first I think?

Comment: Go and look at the standard.  The operators are presented in order of precedence (high to low), and §6.5.2 **Postfix operators** comes before §6.5.3 **Unary operators**.  (And I see I invented a new operator `i+++`; I meant `i++`!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I should correct: `++i++` == as  `++(i++)` == `++ ( 1 + 1)` Thanks I just saw Its very rare case so I confuse

Comment: Better.  Of course, since I'm nicking pits, the result of `i++` is the old value of `i`, so it is more like: `++(i+=1, i-1)`, but since the whole thing is illegal, this whole debate is a little like the great questions of how many angels can dance on the head of a pin (and the answer to that does not appear to be 42, even though 42 is The Answer to The Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should not be doing this, as it obscures the code.
The reason you're getting the error is that the post-increment has precedent and thus returns an r-value, i.e. `++i++ == ++(i++)` which cannot be incremented.

However, you *can* use `(++i)++` since the pre-increment (apparently, on VS2010) returns `i` itself, an l-value which *can* be post-incremented.

Comment: The result of `++i` isn't an lvalue either; `(++i)++` yields exactly the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... this worked on VS2010.

Comment: Are you sure?  If so, then VS2010 is non-conforming (which wouldn't be surprising).

Comment: Yes. `printf("%d",(++i)++);` works (prints 6)

Comment: Then VS2010 is not conforming, in a somewhat scary way.  The standard is pretty clear; the result of an assignment is not an lvalue, and both prefix and postfix ++ have similar constraints.  gcc rejects it with an "invalid lvalue in imcrement" diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
printf("%d",++i++)
```

==>

```
printf("%d",(++i)++)
```

And

==>

```
 printf("%d",(++i)); &(++i)++ ==> (++i) = (++i) +1;
```

See you use (++i) as a left value.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing increment to a constant..

In your case

```
++i => 6
++i++ => 6++ //this is not possible. Gives lvalue error
++i+10 => 6+10 => 16 //this is possible
```

So doing ++i++ is not good.  **Post increment/decrement, pre increment/decrement possible only on variables**. At runtime your statement will become a constant so it gives lvalue error here.

```
++i => 6 => i=6;
i++ => 6 => i=7;
printf("%d",i); //7
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `++i++` is evaluated as `++(i++)` which is illegal in C as the postfix increment returns a value and prefix incrementing on a that *value* makes no sense.

What you have is somewhat equivalent to: `++(5)` which is obviously illegal as you can apply prefix increment on something that's not a l-value.