# foo((&i)++) gives compilation error in C

Tags: c

In the Following example, I expect that foo((&i)++) will evaluate to foo(4 + address of (i)) assuming that the int size is 4 Byte however it gives a compilation error at this line

anyone has an explanation ?

```
void foo(int*);
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    foo((&i)++);
}
void foo(int *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

Comment: Also `foo(1234++)`  or `foo((i*2)++)` don't compile, for similar reasons.

Comment: Even if you could use `++` on an rvalue, postfix `++` evaluates to the original value, not the incremented value.

Comment: In your question, the thing is `++` operator can't applied on an expression and you are applying `++` on `&i` that is an expression. Assume `i++`  is like `i = i + 1;`  similarly `(&i)++;` as `&i = &i + 1;` Can you assign to an expression? That what compilation error: Read this Q&A also [Why `++i++` gives "L-value required error" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850934/1673391)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is "lvalue required for increment operator". The problem is that `++` needs to operate on a variable - you increment, AND STORE THE RESULT.

You cannot store the result of the increment operation in `(&i)`.

To get `foo` to operate on an integer that is stored at the address you *appear* to want, you can do one of the following (I'm sure you can think of others):

```
foo(&i);
int *p = &i; foo(p++);
```

The second option will correctly call `foo` with a pointer to `i`, but will increment that pointer for the next time (which seems to be what you were trying to do with your code - except you had nowhere to put that value. By declaring a separate pointer `p`, I created that storage space. But realize that `p` is now pointing "nowhere" - if you access it again, you will get [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

If you wanted to point to the *next location after the address of i* you would have to do

```
foo(++p);
```

but that would be undefined behavior (since there is no way of knowing what is stored in the next location after i; most likely it will be `p` but that is not guaranteed.)

Pointers. Powerful, dangerous, and slightly mysterious.

Answer (score 3):

The operand of `++` must be an lvalue -- a variable or other location in memory that can be modified -- since it adds 1 to it and replaces it with the result. `&i` is not an lvalue, it's just an expression that yields the address of `i`.

Also,

> foo(4 + address of (i))

is wrong since you're using postfix `++` rather than prefix `++`. The value of EXPR++ is EXPR (with the side effect of changing the variable that expr refers to).

To get the value you want, just use

```
foo(&i + 1)
```

Note, however, that this is likely to result in undefined behavior ... depending on just what foo does with its argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing and trying to store back the *address* of `i`. How and where does the result get stored back? It can't, because `&i` doesn't exist in memory.

I think you want to do this instead:

```
 foo((&i)+1);
```